# How to select by using custom date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a custom date (dynamic build/input) as like '2013-5-13'
but my mysql database store as '2013-05-13'
so where i try to retrieve it out as like

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE XDATE='2013-5-13' >>> it return me ZERO result
```

but

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE XDATE='2013-05-13' >>> it return me CORRECT result
```

so how to solve this one directly in mysql statement?

Comment: Clean your date before using it in your query isn't an option?

Comment: Use `DATE_FORMAT` with both columns

Comment: is XDATE a date/datetime field? or is it a varchar?

Answer (score 6):

use this `%c` in [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

```
     select *  from TBL WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`XDATE`,'%Y-%c-%d') = '2013-5-13'
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dac66/7)

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
DATE_FORMAT(`XDATE`,'%Y-%c-%d')
```

#### Query

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`XDATE`, '%Y-%c-%d') = '2013-5-13'
```

[**MySql  DATE_FORMAT Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
%c  Month, numeric (0..12)
```

Comment: @echo_Me you right. I equally with sql col type. I have to equally with string. Yes, should be `%c`

Answer (score 1):

Before querying the database just use `strtotime()` to set correctly...

```
 $date = "2013-5-16";
 $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE XDATE='".$date."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to convert both dates and then check.

Answer (score 0):

This answer works only if your input is always in the format "year-month-day"

```
$date = '2013-5-13';
$parts = explode('-', $date);
$year = $parts[0];
$month = $parts[1];
$day = $parts[2];
//i assume that $year is always valid. Possible checks are left to the reader
//(lol i've always dreamed to write that sentence somewhere)
$month = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
$day = str_pad($day, 2, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);

$clean_date = "$year-$month-$date"; //note the quotes
```

Now you can use `$clean_date` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2013-5-13', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

in the WHERE part:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE XDATE=DATE_FORMAT('2013-5-13', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

[MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: it's probably better to use %c instead of %m, but this is the correct approach and it's the only answer that will make use of an index on xdate, if it exists

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way would be to use the MySQL `DATE()` function:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE(date_col) = DATE("2013-5-01")
```

[MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Answer (score 0):

use this query :-

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(XDATE)=strtotime('2013-5-13')
```